# cv2.imwrite not giving image output

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I'm currently doing an internship remotely and I got to code a Visualization Tool with D3.JS but here is not the part where I got a problem.
To fix the subject I got some file called episodes, which contain data about the path of a robot, if he succeeds or failed and the different point in cartesian coordinate.
(BTW I'm French I apologize in advance if there is some grammar issues)
So I got a small Python program that interpret these data contained in these .p files here's the code :

```
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #PyQT is require or tkinter
import numpy as np
import cv2
#This script aligns the true position to position given by orbslam.
#Load episode with id. #This loads the dictionary containing all information about an episode.
trajectory_dir = "ORBSlam/"
episode_id = 0
episode = pickle.load(open( trajectory_dir+"episodeStats"+str(episode_id)+".p", "rb" ))
#Extract useful data from the dictionary
pose_env = episode["pose_env"]
images_RGB = episode["rgb"]
images_depth = episode["depth"]
actions_orb = episode["orb_action"]
actions_best = episode["best_action"]
goal_distances = episode["goal_distance"]
success = episode["success"]

#Save observations into images.
for i in range(len(images_RGB)):
    cv2.imwrite( trajectory_dir+"RGBs"+str(episode_id)+"/"+str(i)+".png", images_RGB[i] )
    cv2.imwrite( trajectory_dir+"Depths"+str(episode_id)+"/"+str(i)+".png", images_depth[i]*255 )

#Display 2D trajectories.
x_env = []
y_env = []
for i in range(len(pose_env)):
    #add x,y coordinates of the translation
    x_env.append(pose_env[i][0,3])
    y_env.append(pose_env[i][2,3])
plt.plot(x_env,y_env)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

The problem here is that during the loop where it's supposed to output png image, in fact there is no output in the folder and since it's a silent function I don't know what the error is, I created both folder in ORBSlam folder (RGBs and Depths), so do you think it's something about permissions of writing or something like that ? (I'm working on macOS)
Thanks in advance for all the responses.
EDIT : I find why I've got no output images, I simply forgot to create a folder with the name of `episode_id` (Basically 0,1,2,...) in Depths and RGBs folder, my bad it was a dumb mistake

Comment: Hello Augustin,  could you try replace your imwrite path with `cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(trajectory_dir, "RGBs" + str(episode_id), str(i)+ ".png"), images_RGB[i])`, another good practice would be to `cv2.imshow()` the images that would be saved to see if images are being generated properly, for this to work, make sure you are using ssh with x forwarding and it is setup properly.

Comment: I try with os.path.join but it hasn't worked, if I use cv2.imshow() a python window is starting but never show freeze instantly and become unresponsive, I will ask directly to my tutor I think if I haven't found the issues before the end of the day, thanks for try to help btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved : a folder inside where missing to get the output